# How to save a string with multiple words with scanf()

Tags: c, string, char

I just started programming in C and I was wondering why I can't store a string with multiple words with scanf().

For example, I enter: "That's an example" and it's stores only the first word "That's"

My code:

```
int main(void) {

    char string[100];
    
    printf("Please enter something: ");
    scanf("%s", &string);
    printf("You entered: %s", string);


    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Especially considering that `fgets`  must be passed a buffer size, so it's easier to not not have buffer overflows.

Comment: On another note, the `%s` format for `scanf` expects a `char *` argument. When you pass `&string` you're passing an argument of type `char (*)[100]`, which is wrong and leads to undefined behavior. The correct value to pass is `&string[0]`, or just plain `string` (as that will *decay* to the correct value).

Comment: Okay thanks. Do I have to include a new library for `fgets`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let `scanf()` read more than one word with the character class conversion specifier: `%[^\n]` will stop at the newline and leave it pending in the input stream. Note that you must tell `scanf` the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array to avoid undefined behavior on long input lines. When passing an array to `scanf()`, you should not pass its address as `&string`, but just pass `string` as arrays decays into a pointer to their first element when passed as a function argument.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    int c;
    
    for (;;) {
        printf("Please enter something: ");
        /* initialize `string` in case the `scanf()` conversion fails on an empty line */
        *string = '\0';
        if (scanf("%99[^\n]", string) == EOF)
            break;
        printf("You entered: %s\n", string);
        /* read the next byte (should be the newline) */
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF)   /* end of file */
            break;
        if (c != '\n')
            ungetc(c, stdin);  /* not a newline: push it back */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that it is much simpler to use `fgets()` for this task:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    
    for (;;) {
        printf("Please enter something: ");
        if (!fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin))
            break;
        /* strip the trailing newline, if any */
        string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("You entered: %s\n", string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 512

int main(void) {

    char string[BUFF_SIZE];

    printf("Enter something: ");
    fgets(string, BUFF_SIZE, stdin);
    printf("You entered: %s", string);

    return (0);
}
```

`fgets()` is the best option

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem in you `scanf();`  I recommend you to remove `&` from it. then your code should see like that:

```
int main(void) {

    char string[100];
    
    printf("Please enter something: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("You entered: %s", string);


    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your remark is correct, but it does not address the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but it doesn't store the whole string, I entered.

Answer (score 0):

In the c language, there is no data type called a string.
A **string** is stored as an **array of characters**.

Moreover, the variable itself points to the first element of the array. Therefore, there is no need to use the '&' operator to pass the address.

So, all you have to do is the following:

```
int main(void) {

char string[100];
printf("Please enter something: ");
scanf("%s", string);
printf("You entered: %s", string);
return (0);
}
```

Don't use '&' in scanf function.

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as Muhammad's and, while your remark is correct, it does not address the OP's question. Also learn how to indent the code.

Comment: Thank you, for mentioning it. I'll look into this and will make the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{

   char string[100];
   printf("Please enter something: ");
   scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string);
   printf("You entered: %s", string);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format the code snippet in your answer correctly.

Answer (score -1):

According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html, `%s` will ignore white-space characters. To capture spaces you would have to use `%c` with the additional size of the input argument, or use `%[` format. Check if `scanf` will add `\0` byte to the end or not.